# CCNet Scheduled Unit Tests with MSTest

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I would like to do scheduled Unit Tests (so the Unit Tests are not always performed, while Building the project).
Is it possible? If yes, how to?

Answer (score 0):

Created second project in ccnet.config. Each project has its own trigger and performs one task (build or unit test).